# Вывести атрибуты класса на страницу

Tags: python, django

Есть класс:

```
class Product():
def __init__(self, id, name):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.category = "category"
    self.animal = "animal"
    self.count = 33
    self.price = 1299
```

Хочу вывести его атрибуты на страницу, но у меня не получается. Что я делаю не так?

views.py:

```
def class_1(request):
    pet = Product(1, 'cat')
    context = {
        'id': pet.id,
        'name': pet.name,
        'category': pet.category,
        'count': pet.count,
        'price': pet.price
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if id %}
    <h1>ID: {{id}}</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Пустая страница? Тег h1 пустой или отсутствует?

Comment: У меня есть еще один словарь во views, он отображается, а этот нет - просто пустое место там. где должны быть данные

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ошибка в Вашем urls.py. Должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import class_1


  urlpatterns = [
    path('', class_1, name='index'),
  ]
```